# SQL Ordering when having NULL values

Tags: sql, decimal, numeric

I've to order sql results by ascending numeric values.
My code is something like that:

```
ORDER BY CAST(`baseData` AS DECIMAL(10,2)) {$dir} ";
```

It works so good, but there is a problem: it puts all NULL values on the bottom, i think it considers them like "0".
I need to put on the bottom all NULL values, how can I modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, It works:

```
ORDER BY baseData = '', CAST(`baseData` AS DECIMAL(10,2)) {$dir} ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL

For MYSQL

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(CAST(`baseData` AS DECIMAL(10,2)),0)
```

For Oracle

```
ORDER BY NVL(CAST(baseData AS DECIMAL(10,2)),0)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7522e/2)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test(
t varchar(5)
);


insert into  test
values('123'),('234'),('222'),(NULL);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select coalesce(cast(t as decimal(10,2)),0)
from test
order by coalesce(cast(t as decimal(10,2)),0);
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7522e/1/0)**:

```
| COALESCE(CAST(T AS DECIMAL(10,2)),0) |
----------------------------------------
|                                    0 |
|                                  123 |
|                                  222 |
|                                  234 |
```

Comment: Nope, it randomize results (I'm using MySql)

Comment: The updated answer does not have an order by clause in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put all Nulls at the head

```
  ORDER BY CAST(`baseData` AS DECIMAL(10,2)) NULLS FIRST
```

if you want to put all Nulls at the bottom

```
  ORDER BY CAST(`baseData` AS DECIMAL(10,2)) NULLS LAST
```

if you want Nulls to be considered as 0, cast them as Pheonix did

```
  ORDER BY Nvl(CAST(`baseData` AS DECIMAL(10,2)), 0) -- Oracle, MS SQL
  ORDER BY IfNull(CAST(`baseData` AS DECIMAL(10,2)), 0) -- MySQL
```

if you want Nulls being last, but being shown like 0

```
  select ...
         Nvl(CAST(`baseData` AS DECIMAL(10,2)), 0) -- Oracle, MS SQL
         ...
   order by CAST(`baseData` AS DECIMAL(10,2)) NULLS LAST
```

Comment: but where have I to put parameter "asc" or "desc"? after or before NULLS LAST?

Comment: ORDER BY [Your Expression] ASC NULLS LAST